# R foreach %dopar% : export results to main R process

Tags: r, foreach

%dopar% forks the main R process into several independent sub-processes. Is there a way to make these sub-processes communicate with the main R process, so that data can be 'recovered' ?

```
require(foreach) 
require(doMC) 
registerDoMC() 
options(cores = 2 )

a <- c(0,0)
foreach(i = 1:2 ) %do% {
    a[i] <- i
}
print(a) # returns 1 2

a <- c(0,0)
foreach(i = 1:2 ) %dopar% {
    a[i] <- i
}
print(a) # returns 0 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the foreach documentation:

> The foreach and %do%/%dopar% operators provide a looping construct
>   that can be viewed as a hybrid of the standard for loop and lapply
>   function. It looks similar to the for loop, and it evaluates an
>   expression, rather than a function (as in lapply), **but it's purpose is
>   to return a value** (a list, by default), rather than to cause
>   side-effects.

```
Try this:
a <- foreach(i = 1:2 ) %dopar% {
  i
}
print(unlist(a))
```

Comment: I did read the documentation, and found it obscure... Your answer brings light in all this! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your result to be a dataframe, you could do:

```
 library(data.table)
 result <- foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% {
      i
 }
 result.df <- rbindlist(Map(as.data.frame, result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Karl, I now understand the purpose of '.combine'

```
a <- foreach(i = 1:2 , .combine=c) %dopar% {
    return(i)
}
print(a) # returns 1 2
```

Comment: No need for `return` (and indeed it’s somewhat un-functional).